# How to insert new interface types into an array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

What i'm trying to achieve is to have this structure type:

```
let chartDataSets: Array<ChartDataSets> = new Array<ChartDataSets>();
chartDataSets = [
                {
                    backgroundColor: "#29b6f6",
                    borderColor: "#0086c3",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "#0086c3",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#73e8ff",
                    pointRadius: 3.5,
                    fill: false
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "#f44336",
                    borderColor: "#ba000d",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "#ba000d",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#ff7961",
                    pointRadius: 3.5,
                    fill: false
                }
            ]
```

By doing this:

```
data.forEach(element => {
                chartDataSets.push(this.buildDatasets(element, timeSpan));
            });
otherData.forEach(otherElement => {
                chartDataSets.push(this.buildDatasets(otherElement, timeSpan));
            });
```

I've to do this in that way because I don't know how many objects the array will have. So I need to iterate through the data returned from a service in order to know how many objects there are going to be in the array.
But what I achieve with the push command is to generate only an array of one object instead of generating multiple objects of ChartDataSets into the array.

Here are the interfaces declaration:

```
export interface ServiceResponse {
    Date: Date;
    Amount: number;
    Precision: number;
}

export interface ChartDatasets {
     data: ChartPoint[],
     backgroundColor: string,
     borderColor: string,
     pointHoverBorderColor: string,
     pointHoverBackgroundColor: string,
     pointRadius: number,
     fill: boolean
}

export interface ChartPoint {
    x: number | string | Date
    y: number
}
```

the method buildChartDatasets declaration:

```
protected buildDatasets(element: EacSubmissionResponseModel, timeSpan: TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Day): ChartDataSets {
        let chartDataset: ChartDataSets = {};

        let chartResponse: ChartPoint[] = [{
            x: element.Date,
            y: element.Amount
        }]

        chartDataset.data = chartResponse;

        return chartDataset;
    }
```

This is the response that I get, shown in chrome developer tools:

[image: results]

The first one is the desired result, the second one is what I actually got.
Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: can you show us the declaration of the type `ChartDataSets` ?

Comment: Yeah, can you provide that type and details around your `this.buildDatasets` method. Also, you can use a syntax like this to clean that up a little `const chartDataSets = data.concat(otherData).map(e => this.buildDatasets(e, timeSpan));`

Comment: ChartDatasets contains all the properties you see in the first example. Just  in order to get type checking. Buildchartdatasets method Maps some of the entity returned by the service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem, this is the way I did it:

```
let chartDataSets: Array<ChartDataSets> = new Array<ChartDataSets>();
let chartPoints: Array<ChartPoint> = new Array<ChartPoint>();

this._service.getData().subscribe(data => {
   data.forEach(element => {
       chartPoints.push(this.buildDatasets(element, timeSpan));
   });

   chartDataSets.push({
       data: chartPoints
   })
});
```

this is the signature for buildDatasets:

```
protected buildDatasets(element: EacSubmissionResponseModel, timeSpan: TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Day): ChartPoint
```

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand well, you have a service returning your `data` and `otherData` variables, which are arrays of `element`s.

Then you have to individually supply each `element` to `this.buildDatasets` to get a `ChartDataSets`, and then push every returned value to your `chartDataSets` Array.

Which means that `this.buildDatasets` has the following signature :

```
buildDatasets(element: T, timeSpan): ChartDataSets
```

With type `T` being the type of each `element` returned. So `data` and `otherData` must be of type `T[]`.

Please check the type of your `data` variable, and the return type of `this.buildDatasets`.

Comment: Yes indeed the element parameter is of type ServiceResponse and te return type of the method is ChartDatasets. They are both like you said but I keep getting only an array of one object

Comment: Can you provide the interface declaration of `ServiceResponse` and `ChartDataSets`, the source code of `buildDatasets`, an example of the `data` variable and the `chartDataSets` array that is generated from it ?

Comment: I've edited my original question, please tell me if you need more info